# How application structure should looks like?

Tags: python, class, theory

I'm trying to create a small database app to keep all clients inside. I would like to write GUI using PyQt5. I have a problem with understanding how app structure should looks like. 
I'd like to have a main class which starts the app and I want to seperate GUI, DB and Main classes in different files.

You can see my code snippets bellow. It don't work because some variables are not recognized and accually I don't understand why.

My thoughts:
1. Window, tab1 objects will be created in main class **init** function
2. When window, tab1 instances were created, the methods inside it's **init** will be called
3. I have window, tab1 objects and it's variables are available for themselves

window.gbT1Main.setLayout(T1LayMain) is not defined for TabNewClient class. Why ? How should I change my code to achieve above requirements? Please explain me how should I connect my classes :(

Window and TabNewClient class (window, tab1)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QTabWidget, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QFormLayout, QLineEdit, QDateEdit, QTextEdit, QRadioButton, QGridLayout
import sys
import datetime

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        # create tab widget
        self.tab = QTabWidget()

        # create MainWindow groupbox
        self.gbMainWindow = QGroupBox()

        # TAB groupBoxes
        self.gbT1Main = QGroupBox()
        self.gbT2Main = QGroupBox("Main2")
        self.gbT3Main = QGroupBox("Main3")

        # Adding tabs
        self.tab.addTab(self.gbT1Main, "Dodaj klienta")
        self.tab.addTab(self.gbT2Main, "Wyszukaj")
        self.tab.addTab(self.gbT3Main, "Statystki")

        # Setting MainWindow title
        self.setWindowTitle("MEDIKAP - gabinet medycyny pracy")

        # Main Window Layout
        self.layMainWindow = QHBoxLayout()

        # Set MainWindow Layout
        self.layMainWindow.addWidget(self.tab)
        self.gbMainWindow.setLayout(self.layMainWindow)

        # set MainWindow layout visible
        self.setLayout(self.layMainWindow)

        #show window
        self.show()

class TabNewClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.CreateTab1Layout()

    def CreateTab1Layout(self):

        self.gbAddClient = QGroupBox("Dane klienta")
        self.gbRodzajBadania = QGroupBox("Podstawa prawna")
        self.gbDane = QGroupBox()
        self.gbComment = QGroupBox("Komentarz")
        self.gbButtons = QGroupBox()

        # TAB1 - layouts
        T1LayMain = QVBoxLayout()
        layDane = QHBoxLayout()

        # TAB1
        layDane.addWidget(self.gbAddClient)
        layDane.addWidget(self.gbRodzajBadania)
        self.gbDane.setLayout(layDane)

        # TAB1 - set layout to Main
        T1LayMain.addWidget(self.gbDane)
        T1LayMain.addWidget(self.gbComment)
        T1LayMain.addWidget(self.gbButtons)

        window.gbT1Main.setLayout(T1LayMain)
```

Main class:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
from guiv3 import Window, TabNewClient

class Main:
    def __init__(self):

        window = Window()
        tab1 = TabNewClient()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Main()

    app.exec_()
```

error:
window.gbT1Main.setLayout(T1LayMain)
NameError: name 'window' is not defined

Comment: could you pls show us the full traceback?

Comment: About the structure, google for MVC - Model - View - Controller, this is a rather common pattern to design software. Database is the model, View is the App. Both are separate things. And they are connected by a controller, that negotiates between them.

Comment: https://www.oodesign.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question of why you get an error about 'window' not being defined, I believe it's because there is no `window` variable in the `TabNewClient` class. It looks like you're attempting to refer to the `window` defined in `Main`, but that won't work since that variable isn't in the scope of the `TabNewClient` class. My guess is that you're going to run into the same issue with `gbT1Main`, since that is outside the scope of the `TabNewClient` class as well.

*Edit:* I think I understand what you're attempting here. You want the `gbT1Main` related tab in `window` to hold the layout from `tab1`. To do that, you will need to set `window`'s layout in `Main`:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
from guiv3 import Window, TabNewClient

class Main:
    def __init__(self):

        window = Window()
        tab1 = TabNewClient()
        window.gbT1Main.setLayout(tab1.T1LayMain)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Main()

    app.exec_()
```

That's most likely what you're looking for.

**Important:** this also requires that `T1LayMain` be an attribute of the `TabNewClient` class, so use `self.T1LayMain` inside that class for it to be accessible outside it.

Comment: I am trying to seperate the GUI, database, and some more files and run them (create  GUI, DB objects) inside Main class. Or mayby the better idea is to keep all classes inside one python file? I am wondering what approach is the best to keep my app as much understandable and clear as possible but I don't know how to google it :D

Comment: See my updated answer. I think I get what you're going for, but I'm honestly not sure. I'm mainly trying to get the gist of what `window.gbT1Main.setLayout(T1LayMain)` accomplishes.

Comment: This helped me to get rid of an error with gbT1Main but another problem is GUI window dissapeard right after I run the app. 

When I put below code into file containing window and TabNewClient classes, everything works fine and I can see GUI:

```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Window()
    tab1 = TabNewClient()

    app.exec_()
```